# How to use '::' in spring boot?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

how to use a query from the Postgre to Spring boot?

I used this query to get data in postgre

> "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE delivery_date::date = '2019-10-28' limit 10;"

I'm trying to make a rest fire with an entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="mytable")
public class DeliveryDataEntity implements Serializable {
@Column(name="delivery_date")
private Date delivery_date;

@Column(name="delivery_name")
private String delivery_name;

@Id
@Column(name="delivery_id")
private int delivery_id;
}
```

and my repo code like this

```
@Repository
public interface DeliveryDataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DeliveryDataEntity, Date>{
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE delivery_date = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Page<DeliveryDataEntity> findByUserAndStatusOrderByCreatedAtDesc(Date delivery_date, PageRequest pageRequest
            );
}
```

If I run there are no errors, but the data isn't readable.
I tried changing the query to be like this

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE delivery_date >= ?1", nativeQuery = true)

and
Query(value="SELECT * FROM accounts_data WHERE updated \\= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

but, if I run it will get **null** results.

how do i solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the likely problem be the double colon (`::`) cast operator, which Spring Boot doesn't like, you could try refactoring your query to use a range instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE delivery_date >= '2019-10-28' AND delivery_date < '2019-10-29'
ORDER BY <some column>
LIMIT 10;
```

The logic in the `WHERE` clause simply states to find all records whose delivery dates occur on or after midnight of 28-OCT-2019, and strictly *before* midnight of the following day.

JPA/Hibernate might also support using the `CAST` function, since Postgres does implement `CAST`, so this version might also work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (CAST delivery_date AS date) = '2019-10-28'
ORDER BY <some column>
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I tried using CAST query, but it still doesn't work. I also tried it like this

@Query("select a from mytable a where a.delivery_date <= :delivery_date")

and @Query("from *from mytable where delivery_date = :delivery_date") i'm getting error

Comment: What is the error?  The range query should certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need the (::) operator. If you want to consider only dates (without times), you can use the @Temportal annotation, as explained in this [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date).

Also, I think you don't need to use native queries.